# TypeError Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: arrays, laravel, database, session, typeerror

**I have stored data of user from database in session but when I try to access the ID of user via session then it says Cannot access offset of type string on string.**

**Function where I have created session**

```
function loginUser(Request $req)
{
    $data = $req->input(); //data entered by user in  form

    $email = $data['email'];// input email

    $user_data = User::WHERE(["email" => $email])->first();  //original user data

    if ($user_data == null || $user_data->password != $req['password']) {
        return "email or pass is wrong";
    } else {
        $req->session()->put("user", '$user_data');

        return redirect("/");
    }
}
```

**Code where i am trying to access ID from session**

```
function addCart(Request $req)
{
    if (session()->has("user")) {
        $product_id = $req->product_id; //product_id via form
        $user_id = session()->get("user")['id']; //user_id via session 

        $cart = new Cart;
        //assigning data to db columns
        $cart->product_id = $product_id;
        $cart->user_id = $user_id;
        $cart->save();

        return redirect("/");
    } else {
        return redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: remove quotes from $user_data in $req->session()->put("user", '$user_data'); use without quotes i.e. $req->session()->put("user", $user_data);

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using one of Laravel's own auth systems?

Comment: Research  about auth-middleware (instead of reinventing the wheel)